# Draw Polyline during offline mode in nutiteq

Tags: android, maps, nutiteq

I have been successful in drawing polyline on nutiteq map during internet connections but is there any way where polyline can be drawn when there is no wifi connection(offline mode/no internet access).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Drawing lines on map should not be dependent on online/offline mode at all. Can you explain why this is relevant for your case, what is this line?

Comment: Just for reference: https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d/wiki/Vectorobjects describes how to add Polylines.